# Exclude external links and only scrape internal link in python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scripting, web-crawler

website to fetch links from - http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-previous-listen.html

I want to get a list of all the links on the page and their internal .mp3 links (aapx 20K links)
For eg parent link: http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-previous-listen.html
This has 14 links inside it, which have furthur more link and so on. have a look to get clarity:
1st link in parent: http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20131118.html
1.1.1 link: http://hindi-films-songs.com/main/roberto-48.html
NOW, I need all links under 1.1.1 and so on, so There are 3 level of pages which are to be crawled.
The problem is at the end of every page there is link that goes to main page which isnt to be crawled, how do I exclude it at every level?

My code -

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import colorama

# init the colorama module
colorama.init()

GREEN = colorama.Fore.GREEN
GRAY = colorama.Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX
RESET = colorama.Fore.RESET

# initialize the set of links (unique links)
internal_urls = set()


total_urls_visited = 0


def is_valid(url):
    """
    Checks whether `url` is a valid URL.
    """
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    return bool(parsed.netloc) and bool(parsed.scheme)


def get_all_website_links(url):
    """
    Returns all URLs that is found on `url` in which it belongs to the same website
    """
    # all URLs of `url`
    urls = set()
    # domain name of the URL without the protocol
    domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
        href = a_tag.attrs.get("href")
        if href == "" or href is None:
            # href empty tag
            continue
        # join the URL if it's relative (not absolute link)
        href = urljoin(url, href)
        parsed_href = urlparse(href)
        # remove URL GET parameters, URL fragments, etc.
        href = parsed_href.scheme + "://" + parsed_href.netloc + parsed_href.path
        if not is_valid(href):
            # not a valid URL
            continue
        if href in internal_urls:
            # already in the set
            continue
        print(f"{GREEN}[*] Internal link: {href}{RESET}")
        urls.add(href)
        internal_urls.add(href)
    return urls


def crawl(url, max_urls=50):
    """
    Crawls a web page and extracts all links.
    You'll find all links in `external_urls` and `internal_urls` global set variables.
    params:
        max_urls (int): number of max urls to crawl, default is 50.
    """
    global total_urls_visited
    total_urls_visited += 1
    links = get_all_website_links(url)
    for link in links:
        if total_urls_visited > max_urls:
            break
        crawl(link, max_urls=max_urls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Link Extractor Tool with Python")
    parser.add_argument("url", help="The URL to extract links from.")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--max-urls", help="Number of max URLs to crawl, default is 50.", default=50, type=int)
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    url = args.url
    max_urls = args.max_urls

    crawl(url, max_urls=max_urls)

    print("[+] Total Internal links:", len(internal_urls))
    print("[+] Total URLs:", len(internal_urls))

    domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc

    # save the internal links to a file
    with open(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.txt", "w") as f:
        for internal_link in internal_urls:
            print(internal_link.strip(), file=f)
```

putting `href!="http://hindi-movies-songs.com/index.html"` in the empty tag condition didnt help

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

href not in ["http://hindi-movies-songs.com/index.html"] works for me

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
url = "http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-previous-listen.html"
urls = set()
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
    if a_tag['href'] not in ["http://hindi-movies-songs.com/index.html"]:
        print(a_tag.get('href'))
```

The output is:

```
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20131118.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20121231.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20120327.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20110831.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20101215.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20100404.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20091201.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20090611.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20090105.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-listen-20080523.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-batch4.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index-batch3.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/indexbatch2.html
http://hindi-movies-songs.com/films/index11to25.html
```

Comment: Also, using exclude = "http://hindi-movies-songs.com/index.html" and condition "href != exclude" is also working correctly.

Comment: The results you've sent me are the first level. I need to go to 2 more levels inside each of those links and crawl furthur. and every page has 1 (same) link in the end which isn't to be crawled.